# VBA copy-paste application ontime

Tags: excel, vba

I would need your help please...I would like to copy-paste the values from one cell to another one in the same sheet and this process to be done to an interval of time ( for example: 1 min, 5 min ). Could you please give me an advice, here is my code that I have done it so far ( its copying but its not updating ):

```
Sub F_update()

Dim CurrentWS As Worksheet
Set CurrentWS = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Range("A2:A5").Copy Range("B2")
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:20"), _
               "VBAProject.Module1.LB"  

CurrentWS.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Use direct value transfer instead; e.g. `range("A1") = range("C1").Value2`and disable events if you have a Worksheet_Change going on in the background.

Comment: Also just curious - Do you need it to be a certain time interval? Just asking, because if you're doing it ever 1 minute, because within that time a certain cell value changes, you can skip the time requirement part. If you need it to run every so often, you'll have to keep Excel's macro going and won't be able to do anything else in Excel until it's done.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, I need those values from "A1" to be update in a column after 5 min, in another column after 15 min, in the third column after 30 min, so basically I would like to know what were the value 5,15,30 min ago...and to answer u to the second question: I don't mind if the macro is running/updating because I'm not gonna modify Excel on that time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the application.OnTime function.
add code to ThisWorkBook

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    runTime_1 = Now + TimeValue("00:01:00")
    Application.OnTime runTime, "RunEvent_1"

    runTime_5 = Now + TimeValue("00:05:00")
    Application.OnTime runTime, "RunEvent_5"

    runTime_10 = Now + TimeValue("00:10:00")
    Application.OnTime runTime, "RunEvent_10"

End Sub


'Then have a macros in the workbook to repeat the Ontime command.

Public Sub RunEvent_1()

    'Execute your actions here'
    ' and repeat hear
    DoEvents ' this gives user control if they needs to break exection
    alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:01:00")
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "RunEvent_1"
End Sub

Public Sub RunEvent_5()
    'Execute your actions here'
    ' and repeat hear
    DoEvents ' this gives user control if they needs to break exection
    alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:05:00")
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "RunEvent_5"
End Sub

Public Sub RunEvent_10()
    'Execute your actions here'
    ' and repeat hear
    DoEvents ' this gives user control if they needs to break exection
    alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:10:00")
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "RunEvent_10"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jay!